# I am getting this following error: 21/10/06 21:15:55 ERROR ScalaDriverLocal: User Code Stack Trace: java.lang.Exception: max value not updated

Tags: python, java, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to extract data from Netsuite and load it into Azure Databricks, by scripting a JSON config and running it through Azure Data Factory pipeline. I get the error that is mentioned above:

> ERROR ScalaDriverLocal: User Code Stack Trace:
> java.lang.Exception: max value not updated

Could this be related to an error checkpoint table updation?

I am providing the JSON script I used below. I hope someone can help me figure out the error. Thanks.

```
{
"parallelism": 1,
"onJobFailure": "Fail",
"onEmptyDF": "Fail",
"ignoreInvalidRows": true,
"cleanColumnNames": true,
"jobs": [
    {
        "name": "GenericPassThroughBatchJob.CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE_L1",
        "description": "Extract CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE_L1 data from NetSuite",
        "ignoreInvalidRows": true,
        "cleanColumnNames": true,
        "jdbcInputs": [
            {
                "dataFrameName": "CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE_L1",
                "driver": "com.netsuite.jdbc.openaccess.OpenAccessDriver",
                "flavor": "oracle",
                "url": "${spark.wsgc.jdbcUrl}",
                "keyVaultAuth": {
                    "keyVaultParams": {
                        "clientId": "${spark.wsgc.clientId}",
                        "usernameKey": "${spark.wsgc.usernamekey}",
                        "passwordKey": "${spark.wsgc.passwordkey}",
                        "clientKey": "${spark.wsgc.clientkey}",
                        "vaultBaseUrl": "${spark.wsgc.vaultbaseurl}"
                    }
                },
                "incrementalParams": {
                    "checkpointTablePath": "dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l1/audit/log/checkpoint_log/",
                    "extractId": "NETSUITE_CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE",
                    "incrementalSql": "(select b.NAME as BASE_CURRENCY_CD, c.NAME as CURRENCY_CD, a.EXCHANGE_RATE, a.DATE_EFFECTIVE from Administrator.CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATES a left join Administrator.CURRENCIES b on a.BASE_CURRENCY_ID = b.CURRENCY_ID left join Administrator.CURRENCIES c on a.CURRENCY_ID = c.CURRENCY_ID) a1",
                    "maxCheckPoint1": "(select to_char(max(DATE_EFFECTIVE), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from Administrator.CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATES where DATE_EFFECTIVE > to_date('%%{CHECKPOINT_VALUE_1}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))"
                }
            }
        ],
        "fileOutputs": [
            {
                "dataFrameName": "CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE_L1",
                "format": "PARQUET",
                "path": "dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l1/global_netsuite/CurrencyExchangeRate/table/inbound/All_Currency_Exchange_Rate/",
                "saveMode": "Overwrite"
            },
            {
                "dataFrameName": "CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE_L1",
                "format": "DELTA",
                "path": "dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l1/global_netsuite/CurrencyExchangeRate/table/inbound_archive/All_Currency_Exchange_Rate/",
                "saveMode": "Append"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Checkpoint table updation. Once I rectified the checkpoint value, this error was resolved. I had to set the checkpoint value to min(DATE_LAST_MODIFIED) from the records in the table.